# How can you force Applications that open Safari by default to honor the selected non-Safari default browser?

Tags: macos, safari, security, login

For example, when I use a specific VPN application, the authentication path opens the Safari browser, which cannot work with Yubikey.

Is there a way to convince the application to use a different browser to conduct login activity whether modifying the OS or adding a third party tool / setting?

Comment: Your question risks being closed because you're asking a "why did Apple do this" type of question.  You can try to [edit] it to focus on resolving your problem, instead.

Comment: I would contact the VPN developer to see if they have a solution. Perhaps if you mention the actual VPN software you are using, it possible somebody has an answer for you.

Comment: It’s also too broad.  Please edit so there is a specific problem that can be addressed.  As written, there’s no way to know what app is doing what and why.

Comment: Curious if this is how you went about making Chrome the default browser? - https://macpaw.com/how-to/set-default-browser-mac

Comment: Because the application probably launches Safari explicitly, rather than handing the system a URL.

Comment: @slm that is the method I used to set the default browser.

Comment: @MarcWilson wilson is there a specific set of APIs that use Safari instead of just the default browser?